# Is it possible to do an atomically update all the keys in an object? Something like splice for an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on some undo/redo functionality for a project I'm working on.

Keeping a clean history that enables a good undo/redo means that changes should be atomic because otherwise, the undo/redo will step through the small changes made in a single operation as if they were individual changes themselves.

For arrays, this is possible with `splice`, but I'm not sure if there is an equivalent for objects. It would need to atomically **mutate** every value in the object like a splice does for an array.

I would also like to point out that immutable values aren't an option for this project as it relies completely on mutation for everything.

Comment: Are you using ES6?

Comment: It's javascript, everything is atomic. What undo/redo library are you using?

Comment: As an aside, .splice() doesn't really allow the sort of atomic update you describe for your object, because you can't use it to insert/delete at more than one index at a time.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah my question was really malformed...I figured out the solution, which had nothing to do with the answer :/. I would delete if I could but SO won't let me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSBin Example](https://jsbin.com/litunu/3/edit?js,console)

You could use `Object.assign` to do this:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2};
var next = {a: 3, b: 4};

var x = Object.assign(obj, next);

console.log(x);// { a: 3, b: 4 }
console.log(obj);// { a: 3, b: 4 }
```

Comment: Ah I already knew about this, but I'll accept. My question is actually really bad because I don't present the full picture, but I think I know what I'm going to do now. Thanks anyways :p